# Django "ImportError: No module named requests" after deploying app locally

Tags: python, django

Facts: Installed Django on Windows PC, tried testing an app locally and got this error spit out after trying to running a test HTTP server: "ImportError at /"

Additional facts:
Exception Location: C:\Python27\tutorial\snippets\views.py in , line 8

Relevant code (views.py from the above exception location, line 1-10):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from snippets.models import Snippet, User, Credit_Card, Driver, Pending_Ride, User_Ride
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer, UserSerializer, CreditCardSerializer, DriverSerializer, PendingRideSerializer, UserRideSerializer
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\tutorial\tutorial\urls.py" in <module>
  10.   url(r'^', include('snippets.urls')),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\tutorial\snippets\urls.py" in <module>
  2. from snippets import views
File "C:\Python27\tutorial\snippets\views.py" in <module>
  8. import requests

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named requests
```

App with the structure which I've tried to run:
https://github.com/david-zhou/uberserver

Additional:
I've installed the server by following this guide:
http://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial

During the above process I didn't run into any trouble whatsoever. The server is being ran on a Windows 8 PC. I deployed the app by running the following command after cd'ing to the folder:
"python manage.py runserver"

Please do let me know should any of you require any additional information.

Comment: You should suppy more details. How you run the server. By the way your views seems to be in a bad directory.

Comment: Please include the *relevant* code into your question, if your link were to die, then so would your question

Comment: I've done so, what other information can I post to have this resolved?

Comment: What do you get after "ImportError at /".  You must be getting something like `No module named...`

Comment: Well... do you have [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) installed?

Comment: Run `pip freeze` & post the result so we can see what packages you've actually got installed. If `requests` isn't in the list, then that's your problem.

Comment: Request wasn't installed it seems. Sorry for this noob question, hope no one else has the same 'issue' ever again. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have a package on the local system. Just install package 'requests'.
Try go to C:\path\to\python and `pip.exe install requests`.
If you have not installed pip, check this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip